# Can't read cookie if the length is higher than 1

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

So, I'm using some cookies in my project. I can see my three cookies in my browser and their values.

The problem is when I try to get the value of one of them something strange happens:

If the value is, for example, "1" I can get the value of the cookie. But, if the value length is higher than 1 I get null...

[Picture of the cookie with value "1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk2pd.png) -> [Picture with the cookie value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CooVS.png)

[Picture of the cookie with value "11"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvGo9.png) -> [Picture with the cookie getting null value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wii9L.png)

Here's is how I get my cookie:

```
HttpCookie authenticationCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Test"];
```

Can someone help me?

*EDIT*

Here is how i set my cookie:

```
FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
        var authenticationTicket =
            new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                                          user.Name,
                                          DateTime.Now,
                                          DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout),
                                          false,
                                          _cookieManager.SerializeUserData(user),
                                          FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(
            new HttpCookie(
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                StringHelper.Compress(FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authenticationTicket))));
```

Comment: Show the code where you are setting this cookie value(s), and by saying can't read values with length higher than 1 you mean if you set the value to 9 you can read it?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I added the code where i set the cookie. And yes, if change in the browser the value to 1 character i can read the cookie...